# webjars flat GAV layout

Tags: webjars

Is there a reason to adopt a flat layout in GAV of webjars ?
I mean, all groupId are set to "org.websjars". I like to contribute to webjars with polymer elements (core & paper). Its about 132 artifacts ...
I would like to use groupId like:

- org.webjars.polymers.polymer
- org.webjars.polymers.core
- org.webjars.polymers.paper
- org.webjars.polymers.misc
- org.webjars.polymers.labs
- org.webjars.polymers.deprecated

Good or bad idea / practice ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

We've always used just `org.webjars` since there isn't a concept of a `groupId` in JS package repositories.  That way the `artifactId` can correspond to the NPM / Bower artifact name.  The only plans we have for using a different `groupId` are when we do a Bower sync where we'd make the `groupId` = `org.webjars.bower`.